# can't figure out routine to calculate schedule to display days on calender - algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, calendar

I am doing a calender page to display day, night and off days of shift work.

The schedule goes like this: 7 days off, 4 nights, 3 days off, 1 day off, 3 nights, 3 days off, 4 days and then the 28 day cycle starts all over again. The cycle always starts on Friday.

There are 4 different crews: each one starts a week after the other.

So I have a sql table that just has the month, day and year of the first 28 day cycle of the first crew's 7 off and I suck that into a collection and add the fields to calculate the other crews' starting 7 off.

The calender has a different color to show whether its your day off, nights, days. So I go through the list and use the first day of the cycle as an index into an array of:

```
static int[] DaysArray = new int[28] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,1}; // 0 - day off, 1 - days, 2 - nights
```

All I'm interested in is determining at what point into the 28 day cycle the start of the month is and I just color in the rest of the days with the appropriate color. Here's the routine I'm struggling with:

```
protected int GetDayNightOff(int day)
{
    day--;
    day -= 28;
    day = Math.Abs(day);
    day--;
    return DaysArray[day];
}
```

If the first day of the cycle falls on the 1st, then I want to show the starting color using index 0; the 2nd: index 27; 3rd: index 26 and so on. I know there's a simple solution but I just can't seem to get my head around it.

Hope someone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you array doesn't match what the description for the schedule you gave

Comment: Your `GetDayNightOff(int day)` function only accepts a day of the month as an argument, but shouldn't your algorithm require the date that the cycle first began?

Comment: I would very strongly recommend using built-in date types for this. Date logic is always unexpectedly more tricky than you think and the built-in types usually handle things in a nice, easy to use way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you use `DateTime` and an `enum` instead of magic `int`s. The code will be easier to read, and since dates are actually [pretty hard to get right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result), it's good to use a library instead of doing it yourself. Then you can subtract your target day from the cycle start day and get the [`Days`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx) property of that `TimeSpan`.

```
static Working[] DaysArray = { Working.Off, Working.Off, Working.Off, Working.Off, Working.Off, Working.Off, Working.Off, Working.Nights, Working.Nights, Working.Nights, Working.Nights, Working.Off, Working.Off, Working.Off, Working.Days, Working.Days, Working.Days, Working.Off, Working.Nights, Working.Nights, Working.Nights, Working.Off, Working.Off, Working.Off, Working.Days, Working.Days, Working.Days, Working.Days };
public enum Working
{
    Off,
    Days,
    Nights,
}
public Working GetDayNightOff(DateTime cycleStart, DateTime day)
{
    var days = (day - cycleStart).Days;
    days %= DaysArray.Length;
    if (days < 0)
        days += DaysArray.Length;
    return DaysArray[days];
}
```

The calculations on `days` allow `day` to be far from `cycleStart`.